# Python lxml xpath find node with text()=concat('x', 'y')

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to parse an xml file with python lxml xpath, the structure is like this:

```
<body>
  <tu changedate="20190822T080742Z" creationdate="20190822T085527Z" creationid="blank" changeid="blank">
    <prop type="client"> </prop>
    <prop type="project"> </prop>
    <prop type="domain"> </prop>
    <prop type="subject"> </prop>
    <prop type="corrected">no</prop>
    <prop type="aligned">no</prop>
    <prop type="x-document">Test_EN.docx</prop>
    <prop type="x-Project Id">0001</prop>
    <prop type="x-Product group">A</prop>
    <prop type="x-Product">A</prop>
    <prop type="x-Product">B</prop>
    <prop type="x-TestList">TestValue1</prop>
    <prop type="x-TestList">TestValue2</prop>
    <prop type="x-Sample">SampleText</prop>
    <prop type="x-Test">TestText</prop>
    <prop type="x-Name">TestName</prop>
```

to dynamically find nodes with a function I save the names and values of nodes that I'm looking for to variable names.

```
node_name = x-Sample
node_value = SampleText
xpath_expression = f'//body/tu/prop[@type="{node_name}"][text()="{node_value}"]'
elements = tree.xpath(xpath_expression)
```

The problem is that node_value can contain double quotes and therefore produces an invalid xpath expression. Since I am stuck with lxml and it uses xpath 1.0 I can't escape them in the string.

Looking through stackoverflow I found that apparently this can only be done in xpath 1.0 by using concat. I also found the following function posted:

```
def xpath_string_escape(input_str):
    """ creates a concatenation of alternately-quoted strings that is always a valid XPath expression """
    parts = input_str.split('"')
    return "concat('" + "', \"'\" , '".join(parts) + "', '')"
```

Which then gives me this:

```
xpath_expression = '//body/tu/tuv/prop[@type="x-Sample"][text()="concat('SampleText', '')"]'
```

However this doesn't return the nodes I'm looking for.

Comment: I think it's just a typo: try changing n`ode_name = x-Sample` to `node_name = 'x-Sample'`
and `node_value = SampleText` and to `node_value = 'SampleText'`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative. You can remove the double quotes from your node value with :

```
node_value = translate(//prop[@type="x-Sample"]/text(),'"',"")
```

Then use contains() instead of text() to build your XPath expression :

```
xpath_expression = f'//body/tu/prop[@type="{node_name}"][contains(.,"{node_value}")]'
```